# Running a HTML/PHP/JS project from GitHub on Cloud9 (c9.io) IDE

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide

I am relatively new to Git and Github in general, however I can see that it's possible with c9 to clone a github repo by supplying the said repo's URL with the following process:

1. On the dashboard click 'Create Workspace'
2. Select 'Clone from URL'
3. Enter URL (i.e. https://github.com/u2sonderzug/hybridauth.git)

However, what I don't 'get' at this stage is how would I actually view the changes of something I edited in a web browser? Lets say I edited a page called helloworld.htm. How would I actually pull that up in a web browser, since it doesn't appear to be sitting on a web server?

I think I am missing something fundamental. I usually just work with an sftp connection to my web server on github where I'd edit something in the /www/example.com/file.htm directory and then simply view www.example.com/file.htm in a web browser.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open a php file in your project and click on the run button. This will launch an apache server with a url like this: `http://<workspacename>.<c9usernamer>.c9.io`
Once this is done you can navigate to an HTML file in your project.

Using complex PHP framework are difficult to get running on C9. I have used it for a ZendFramework project but I used an FTP workspace, so I was only editing on C9 but running on my own server.

There is some documentation about getting wordpress to run on C9: https://docs.c9.io/running_wordpress_on_cloud9.html.

As far as javascript is concerned I have run nodejs and meteor projects on C9. The only issue I have faced is the 1GB limit on the workspace, but this is easily solved by a bit of planning.

Also, multiple javascript files (client-side code) works great with code-completion etc.

Comment: Thank you @Mubix, this definitely fills in a big part of the picture for me - especially in the realm of HTML. I can understand how this might work in certain contexts, but with a complex PHP website (i.e. using a framework like Cake, CodeIgniter) - I get the feeling something like this wouldn't work. Do you have any experience working with this with PHP or more complicated JavaScript scripts (that work with several files)?

Comment: Added some more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) to deploy your PHP app. It is integrated directly into c9. I've used c9.io and Heroku to quickly develop and deploy apps. Go to the deploy tab in c9, log into Heroku, add a deploy server and click deploy. Heroku will automatically detect that it is a PHP app and set up the server for you.

If you want to take a look at the PHP/JS/HTML app I made on heroku and c9.io it's here: http://gasbro.herokuapp.com